# Trouble with text replace in array Javascript (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to remove 'hello' substring from each object field in objects array.
And i have an error "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null". It happens, because i try to change object field in loop. But What to do? :) 
I use AngularJS.

```js
var array = [
    {text: 'hello user1'},
    {text: 'hello user2'},
    {text: 'user3'},
    {text: 'hello user4'},
];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].text.indexOf('hello') + 1) {
        array[i].text = array[i].text.replace('hello','');
    }
}

// For demo
document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Comment: Problem is somewhere else, your code works

Comment: @trigger I edited your question, care to hit "Run code snippet" and tell us what you see?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition condition is not correct.

> The [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found

change your condition to

```
if(array[i].text.indexOf('hello') > -1){
    //Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: While I agree that this is better practise, the `+1` method should actually work too.

Comment: indeed, indexOf('hello') returning -1 +1 means 0, which should be false, else it should evaluate to true, so this shouldn't be the problem, but it's surely a better practice :P

Answer (score 0):

Change `+` to `> -1`

indexOf() returns the index of the string searched, in case it's not found returns -1.

if `indexOf > -1` it means that there is some hello word in the string

```js
var array = [
 {text: 'hello user1'},
 {text: 'hello user2'},
 {text: 'user3'},
 {text: 'hello user4'},
];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].text.indexOf('hello') > -1) {
    array[i].text = array[i].text.replace('hello','');
  }
}
    
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Your issue is due to another piece of code, this one works perfectly.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "invalid"! If it's corrupted you can't!